# App crashes when adding clickListener

Tags: android

I have an app that is setting the contentView when images are clicked.This one from my main.xml loads the options.xml fine.

```
settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 setContentView(R.layout.options);

            }

        });
```

But when I add a listener to an image that is inside the options.xml the app crashes upon launch.I am referencing the image via the code below and showing the clickListener I am adding.

```
//ReturnHome is inside options.xml
//Adding this in my mainapp.java
 returnHome = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.returnHome);
    returnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            ***APP CRASHES EVERY TIME WHEN I ADD THIS****   
            }

    });
```

Trying to see if there was an error thrown but LogCat does not seem to show anything.

Comment: If application crash with that code, LogCat would 99% (if not 100) capture the Exception. Try putting a break point there to see if it is really that line cause the problem.

Comment: I do not know how to debug but LogCat is catching something.It says the following where 120 is the line I have the code on.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` for the returnHome image is in context of the application.

If in your applicaiton `onCreate()` you set `setContentView(R.layout.main);` when you call `findViewById` it will be looking at `main.xml` for the image `returnHome`, which obviously isn't there because its on `options.xml`, as a result you will get a NullPointerException, because if can't find what you are asking it to.

Instead of declaring the image listener for returnHome in the context of main.xml try doing it after changing the layout, maybe as a method:

```
private void changeView()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    returnHome = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.returnHome);
    returnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Perform whatever.....  
        }
    });
}
```

Then change the first onclick listener to:

```
settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        changeView();
    }
});
```